# React Native custom class not setting properties

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, sqlite

I create a class of name UserInfo in which i stored user information in variables and i call those variable in different screens

```
    class UserInfo {
    constructor(props) {
        this.username = "Test"
    }
}

export default (new UserInfo())
```

And i call it on other Screens like this **UserInfo.username** and it works fine

But now i want to retrieve user information from local database, so i created a method in UserInfo class which fetch data from local database

```
    class UserInfo {
    constructor(props) {
        this.username = ""
        this.getUserInfo
    }

    getUserInfo = () =>{
        db.transaction((tx) => {
            tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM users', [], (tx, results) => {
                let row = results.rows.item(0);
                console.log("UserID: " + row.id) // return value from db, working
                this.username = row.id
            });
        });
    }

}

export default (new UserInfo())
```

But now its return empty value but in console value is show, Am i missing something. I re set the username value by calling a getUserInfo method at the end of constructor...

Comment: you need to call the method - `this.getUserInfo()` instead of `this.getUserInfo`

Comment: already tried bro, same result...

Comment: ok. Please correct that in the question so that you don't get similar answers from the next person.

Answer (score 0):

The `db.transaction` is an `asynchronous` call, it might happen that you are calling `UserInfo.username` before the execution of `this.username = row.id` statement. Instead of directly accessing `username`, call the `UserInfo.getUserInfo()` and get the resolved value using promise, like

```
UserInfo.getUserInfo().then(username => {
    /* do whatever you want to do with username */
});
```

The changes that you need to do in `getUserInfo` is as follows

```
getUserInfo = () => {
  return new Promise((resove, reject) => {
     db.transaction((tx) => {
        tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM users', [], (tx, results) => {
            let row = results.rows.item(0);
            console.log("UserID: " + row.id) // return value from db, working
            this.username = row.id;

            resolve(this.username);

        }, (ts, err) => { 
            /* handle the failed case here */
            reject();
        });
    });
  }); 
}
```

Hope this will help!

Comment: What value you are getting while calling `UserInfo.getUserInfo().then(...)`?

Comment: nothing, it showing error. I was previously doing like <Text>{UserInfo.username}</Text>

Comment: but now i used as your above code its showing error

Comment: Oh, you are using this inside render method!, You need more changes, you need to call the function first then store the result 
 inside `state`, then display the same using <Text>

Comment: i tried it like this: UserInfo.getUserInfo().then(username => {
            /* do whatever you want to do with username */
            this.setState({username:username})
        });

Comment: Now in the render method, do like `<Text>{this.state.username}</Text>`, it shoudl work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170868/discussion-between-prasun-pal-and-digital-jedi).

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be losing the scope of "this"

Can you try the following and see if it works?

```
class UserInfo {
  constructor(props) {
    this.username = ""
    this.getUserInfo()
  }

  getUserInfo = () => {
    let ref = this; // save a reference to to this
    db.transaction((tx) => {
      tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM users', [], (tx, results) => {
        let row = results.rows.item(0);
        console.log("UserID: " + row.id) // return value from db, working
        ref.username = row.id // save the username using the reference
      });
    });
  }

}

export default (new UserInfo())
```

Comment: How do you check that the username is empty? Where do you use it in your code?

Comment: I call it on another screen like this UserInfo.username & its showing nothing there but if i manually set this.username = "User Name" it shows User Name on other screen

Comment: If you want to display the value in a react component then you should use a class that extends React.Component and use the state to update your UI. Your UserInfo class, when it initialises it has username set to an empty string. If you try to use the username at that moment then username will always be equal to "". If you try to request it at a later time it will be correctly updated. I think you should check how React Components work and how to use their state.

Comment: I dont want it to be a componet class, i just want it to be a basic class

Comment: Then you should handle the updating of the UI yourserlf. This means that when you actually have data for the username you need to notify your other component with the new value.

Comment: Because you're manually setting it. The getInfo function you have is async so it needs some seconds for the value to be updated. This is why it is always empty.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a new instance of your class UserInfo and at that point of time the **value stored** inside your this username variable is the **empty string**. If you want to get the value from database after calling your getUserInfo function then you can return the value from your function and use that value inside your react component as below:-

```
    class UserInfo {
    constructor(props) {
        this.username = ""
        this.getUserInfo
    }

    getUserInfo = () =>{
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => { 
           db.transaction((tx) => {
             tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM users', [], (tx, results) => {
                let row = results.rows.item(0);
                console.log("UserID: " + row.id) // return value from db, working
                // this.username = row.id
                resolve(row.id);
            });
           });
        })
    }
 }

export default (new UserInfo())
```

After return ing your value from your function you can use this value inside your react component as below:-

```
UserInfo.getUserInfo().then(username => {
     this.setState({username})
});
```

store this value inside your state and inside your component you can use it as below:-

```
<Text>{this.state.username}</Text>
```

Comment: still empty bro

Comment: can you check your value of username inside your then function of getUserInfo by console and the value of row.id inside your UserInfo class?

Comment: So your issue is resolved ? Or you still got any issue ?

Answer (score 0):

You can Just Save App.js and the metro again and reload R it... This works for me.
Basically, I think we have to focus on wrapping part for Such a issues.